# What is this feather like bug with no legs?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

Seen on leaf in North Texas, USA in April 2017. Critter will attach itself to any object put next to it.

[image][image]

Comment: Could it be a feather? What made you think it's an animal?

Comment: Can you see any features that appear animal in nature? Eg. Head, eyes, antennae, mouthparts. Could you describe them if yes?

Answer (score 17):

It is a specialized feather called "down" (like in down pillows, etc.)

[image]

> Down feathers have a rachis that is shorter than their longest barb. They are completely plumulaceous and have a fluffy appearance, which results from filamentous, noninterlocking barbules.

[image]

<sub>[Anatomy, Clinical Presentation, and Diagnostic Approach to Feather-Picking Pet Birds](http://www.vetfolio.com/dermatology/anatomy-clinical-presentation-and-diagnostic-approach-to-feather-picking-pet-birds)</sub>

Comment: Great diagram presentation

Answer (score 7):

This indeed simply looks like a feather.

[image: https://pattayadaze.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/feather_h5120.jpg]

<sup>Source: [Pattaya Daze](https://pattayadaze.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/wild-things-262/)</sup>

Many predators, particularly hawks and other birds of prey, will typically pull these whimsical [down feathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather) off of their prey before eating.

[image: hawk stares after meal]

<sup>Source: [Kruger Sightings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFR0wtyZCNk)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Tom Strong Reviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4GXEoubAqw)</sup>

Comment: Wow wonderful gif animation.